# Excel - Formula or Macro to fill a cell based on another cell that links to yet another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

In Excel, I am trying to make a cell based of the values contained in two other cells.

I need Cells X and Y to have data based on Cells L and #, like so....

```
     X     Y      L       1     2     3     4     5     6

A    6     1      1      6;1   6;1   7;1   7;2   7;2   8;1
B    7     2      4      6;1   6;1   7;1   7;2   7;2   8;1
```

So row A, has columns X and Y filled based of the values in the number columns. The specific number needed is what is filled in in column L.

I am not sure the best way to phrase this question. If my example doesn't make sense, I can try to clarify or provide more examples. 
I have no idea if this can be done with fancy formulas or with a VBA macro or two. I am an excel noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly you can do this with a combination of `Left`/`Right`, `Index` and `search`.

In my example images, the user inputs their value in column `D`, and then columns `B` and `C` use the formulea

```
=LEFT(INDEX($F2:$K2,1,$D2),(SEARCH(";",INDEX($F2:$K2,1,$D2))-1))

=RIGHT(INDEX($F2:$K2,1,$D2),(SEARCH(";",INDEX($F2:$K2,1,$D2))-1))
```

respectively

[image: left]

[image: right]

Here, the `Index` function returns the correct column to look at (i.e. the value chosen by the user, the `Search` function finds the position of the semi-colon, and the `left`/`right` functions return the values either side of the semi-colon.

Comment: you should use relative rows: `INDEX($F2:$K2, $D2)` and `MID` instead of `RIGHT`

Comment: @Aprillion Well spotted about the rows. What's the benefit of using `Mid` over `Right`?

Comment: Perfect. That is exactly what I needed. You understood my question exactly.