# Vlookup in excel issue

Tags: excel, range, vlookup

I have a `VLOOKUP` unction in excel that looks like the following:

```
=VLOOKUP(J2,A2:B60,1, FALSE)
```

In `J2` is a number that has a match in cells `B2:60`.  I want the function to find an exact match in that range but return the value thats in that same row but in `column A`.

For some reason the formula I have written above returns `#NA` and I am not sure why.  Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Sample Data:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxkaN.jpg

I am trying to lookup the green cells in the first two orange columns and return the Tier value and not the number but when I type in the formula above it gives me the error depicted in the top right of the picture.

Comment: `vlookup` requires that your 'match' range is the first column in the 'range' you are looking in. Try swapping columns `A` and `B`

Comment: If you have to keep the order of data in columns `A` and `B` you'll need to look into using a combination of `INDEX` and `MATCH`

Comment: I did that and it worked but the problem I am searching for a number and trying to return a string.  Because of this, it returns a `#VALUE` error.  Would there be anyway to work around this?

Comment: `vlookup` doesn't have any issue searching for a number and returning a string. Perhaps update your question with some example data and the current formlua you're using.

Comment: And you're still using this exact formula: `=VLOOKUP(J2,A2:B60,1, FALSE)` ?

Comment: The `#N/A` occurs when it can't find the value it's looking up. In your example, you're looking up a `5`, but that value doesn't appear in the list in column `A`.

Comment: The #NA error is fixed but now it gives me a #VALUE! error

Comment: =VLOOKUP(J2,A2:B60,2, FALSE) is the formula im using.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot showing the formula in the cell and the ranges it's referencing, similar to [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28399632/excel-formula-or-macro-to-fill-a-cell-based-on-another-cell-that-links-to-yet/28399975#28399975)?

Comment: I did if you follow the link in the Question

Comment: It doesn't show the formula in the cell.

Comment: The formula is =VLOOKUP(J2,A2:B60,2, FALSE) and its in the cell where the #VALUE! is

Comment: Nice of you to crop off the column labels so anything we offered would be a guess at best.

Answer (score 0):

In your linked image example, you're getting a #N/A error simply because the value in J2 is 5, but there is no value 5 anywhere in column A to look up.
Rather than displaying #N/A to the user, it might be more meaningful to show a message. Eg.I

= IFERROR(VLOOKUP(J2,A2:B60,2,false), "No tier listed for this value.")